# How large a force could the Mamluk have raised during the Mongol Invasion?

Tags: mongols

I know the Mamluk forces numbered around 20,000 during the [Battle of Ain Jalut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Battle_of_Ain_Jalut). But Wikipedia says that the Mamluks numbered around 200,000 during the [1291 siege of Acre](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Siege_of_Acre_(1291)).
This got me wondering how large a force the Mamlukes could have raised to fight the Mongols after the battle of Ain Jalut. Or was Berke Khan's interefence the deciding factor?